# Authenticate the "same user" using either NTLM or FBA

Tags: sharepoint, authentication, sharepoint-2010, forms-authentication, ntlm

SharePoint 2010 : authenticate the **same user** using either NTLM or FBA

I have been struggling for weeks now trying to achieve the following :

1- Authenticate user Foo using NTLM (windows authentication) on a SharePoint 2010 web site.

2- Authenticate the same user Foo using FBA and a custom membership provider.

The problem I am facing is that when user Foo is authenticated through NTLM he gets one profile with some permissions, and when logging in through FBA, he gets another profile with different permissions.

Is there a way to have my user Foo seen as one single user, even though he is authenticated by different authentication mechanism (NTLM or FBA)

The business need is the following : I want user Foo to be able to login automatically through NTLM when he connects using IE. The same user should be able to login through FBA if he using in iPad for example (we detect the device and redirect the user to FBA login page instead of NTLM)

Thanks in advance for your help.

Laurent

Answer (score 0):

I think you can follow some steps like below.

1. Create a User profile service application.
2. Create custom column to indicate permissions
3. When a user logins just check, in user profile service apllication about the permission
4. you can import other user properties from NTML or FBA to User profile application